# Twitter Highlights URL?

Tags: twitter

Is there a URL for Twitter Highlights so I can view them on web e.g. `highlights.twitter.com`?

Having [issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/266404/not-getting-twitter-highlights-recommendations-on-ios) getting iOS push notifications, hoping for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This is [a feature for the Android and iOS apps](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20172643). It's not available from the web.

Comment: Right, it would need to be some sort of hack. I guess we would need access to Twitter's iOS/Android code? Or is there a way to figure out where a notif is linking to on Android/iOS?